# Application.FileDialog being overwritten

Tags: excel, vba

VBA Excel 2010.

This is only for user to select the excel files.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
Set fd1 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd1
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Select the EXCEL FILES to extract."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
            If .Show = False Then
                End
            End If
    End With
```

And i have in:

```
Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()

strFilePath = Environ("Temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "DD.MM.YYYY HH.MM.SS")
MkDir strFilePath 'create a path to store selected email

Set ObjOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set fd2 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd2
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select CASH DIVISION EMAIL that contains attachment to extract."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
            If .Show = True Then
                SourceEmail2 = .SelectedItems(1)
            End If
    End With
Set msg = ObjOL.CreateItemFromTemplate(SourceEmail2)
msg.display
msg.Close olDiscard
```

So basically i have 10 Excel files, selected using the first `FileDialog(fd1)`, and i have 1 email selected using `fd2`.

`fd1` and `fd2` both declared public

the issue is when i run another subroutine:

```
For x = 1 To fd1.SelectedItems.Count
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=fd1.SelectedItems(x)
    '..code here..
Next x
```

Problem now is `fd1.SelectedItems(x)` is now `fd2.SelectedItems(x)`. Apparently `fd1` is being overwritten by `fd2`.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like as follows (though did you really want to just open the Excel files at the end?).Key point here is to load the Excel file names into a collection variable and pass that between subs so you can later access.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()

    two
    three one

End Sub

Public Function one() As Collection

    Dim fd1 As FileDialog

    Set fd1 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd1

        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Select the EXCEL FILES to extract."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

        If .Show = False Then
            End
        End If

        Dim col As Collection
        Set col = New Collection

        Dim i As Long

        With fd1.SelectedItems

            For i = 1 To .Count
                col.Add .Item(i)
            Next i

        End With

        Set one = col

    End With

End Function

Public Sub two()

    Dim strFilePath As String

    strFilePath = Environ$("Temp") & "\" & Format$(Now, "DD.MM.YYYY HH.MM.SS")

    MkDir strFilePath                            'create a path to store selected email

    Dim ObjOL As Object
    Set ObjOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim fd2 As FileDialog
    Set fd2 = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    Dim SourceEmail2 As String

    With fd2

        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select CASH DIVISION EMAIL that contains attachment to extract."
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"

        If .Show = True Then
          SourceEmail2 = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If

    End With

    Dim msg As Object

    Set msg = ObjOL.CreateItemFromTemplate(SourceEmail2)

    msg.display
   ' msg.Close olDiscard

End Sub

Public Sub three(ByVal col As Collection)

    Dim x As Long

    For x = 1 To col.Count
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=col.Item(x)
        '..code here..

    Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Did this make sense?

Comment: +1. Thanks for your response. I managed to get the solutions after further browsing couple months back when i had this problem. Sorry i am not really active here. Really appreciate you taking your time to answer my question.